# Solace Multi-Node Routing Port

Tags: solace

I am trying connect Solace appliances using Multi-Node Routing. May I know what ports do I need to open in my firewall to connect Solace appliances using Multi-Node Routing?

Answer (score 3):

The SMF port and the routing control port need to be opened for MNR. By default, the SMF port is 55555 for non-compressed data and 55003 for compressed. The routing control port is 55556.